# Настройки сайта в бд

Tags: php, html, mysql

Насколько это правильно хранить настройки сайта в БД?

Например я хочу создать сайт с панелью администратора,где будут опции по смене названия сайта, описания, тэгов и т.д. Нужно ли для этого создавать таблицу (где будет всего лишь 1 строка)? Или же можно обойтись без базы данных?

Comment: Создайте таблицу и храните там нужные данные

Comment: Да, это правильно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так и надо делать: всё, что может поправить администратор через веб-интерфейс, должно храниться в БД. А каким именно образом: отдельными полями в строке или по одной строке на каждое значение — это уже детали реализации.

Также, данные которые изменяются редко, а читаются при каждом запросе, сто́ит каким-то образом кешировать чтобы меньше обращаться к базе.

Comment: А есть ли разница в плане нагрузок между хранением в одной строке, и хранением данных на каждой строке?

Comment: Одна строка читается быстрее. Но при использовании кеша разницы нет.

Comment: А как сделать например чтобы в одной таблице хранилась лишь одна строка?Поставить запрет на создание еще одной?

Answer (score 1):

Это нормально, так как позволяет сохранять данные в том числе в резервных копиях базы данных, что иногда критически важно, особенно, если один и тот же движок используется для обслуживания нескольких проектов и вы не можете хранить настройки на уровне системы контроля версий. Содержимое таблицы можно кэшировать, поэтому можно избежать частых запросов к базе данных. Как правило, стараются не хранить все в одной строке, если это не JSON (хотя это тоже считается дурным тоном, если СУБД не поддерживает этот тип, MySQL не поддерживает). Лучше каждую настройку хранить в отдельной записи по принципу ключ-значение. Это позволит вам наращивать количество настроек, не меняя структуры таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Если данные статичны, то храните всё в файле типа conf.php, если динамичные, то в базе. Сам так делаю.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас по-моему все современные проекты (CMS, Site management, etc) хранят настройки в БД, чего плохого-то? Раньше использовали всякие config.php и иже с ними...